# Page is not rendering in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to get the pages by using URL but components are not rendered in the browser even I am not getting the error. So it's very hard to resolve the error.
Please Help me to get the issue.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';

class ToDoApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="ToDoApp">
                    <Route path="/" exact strict Component={Index} />
                    <Route path="/welcome" exact strict Component={WelcomePage} />
                    <Route path="/login" exact strict Component={Login} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div><h1>Welcome</h1></div>);
    }
}

class WelcomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Welcome Page
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            username: 'Ganesh',
            password: '',
            hasLoginFailed: false,
            showSucessMessage: false
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.loginCheck = this.loginCheck.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value // for declaring variable we use []
        })
    }

    loginCheck() {
        if (this.state.username === "Ganesh" && this.state.password === 'admin') {
            console.log('successful');
            this.setState({ showSucessMessage: true, hasLoginFailed: false })
        } else {
            console.log('failed');
            this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true, showSucessMessage: false })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {/* True && 'String Value' -> String Value
                    False &&  'String Value' -> false */}
                {this.state.hasLoginFailed && <div>Invalid Login</div>}
                {this.state.showSucessMessage && <div>Valid Login</div>}

                UserName : <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                Password : <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <button onClick={this.loginCheck}>Login</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default ToDoApp
```

if I put localhost:3000/login -> Login Component should be displayed
if I put localhost:3000/welcome -> WelcomePage Component should be displayed

But now I am getting the blank page

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example using a service like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: When you pass a component to the route, make sure the `component` property is  lower case. Turn `Component={}` in to `component={}` e.g. `<Route path="/" exact strict Component={Index} />` should be `<Route path="/" exact strict component={Index} />`

Comment: Hi Ganesh, even if you don't see anything on the screen you may have details of the error in the development Console log.  Providing any details there will help us help you.

Comment: Thank you Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route,  } from "react- 
router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Pages/Home';

function App() {
return (
 <>
 <Router>
    <Routes>
    <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
 </>
)} 
export default App;
```

Comment: Use this it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).